# How to exclude R.java from Git tracking (after the fact)?

Tags: git, gitignore

I thought that I was pretty familiar with how to use `.gitignore` (which still works great for me for excluding top level directories), but I now discovered that multiple `R.java` files from various libraries used in my application are being tracked and I would like to stop tracking them.

I tried adding the line `R.java` to the `.gitignore` in the top level directory, but `git status` keeps reporting them as modified.

I then tried adding the line `*/gen/` to the `.gitignore` in the top level directory, but `git status` still reports them as modified.

What is the trick to tell git to stop tracking them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.gitignore` should stop them from being indexed. Did you delete the unwanted files with `git rm` or `rm`?

Comment: No, I didn't. Is that what I missed?

Comment: Yep, .gitignore does only affect what changes are being indexed and not files which are already commited.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first remove them from the repo ( `git rm` or `git rm --cached` and commit) for the ignore to work as git does not ignore tracked / versioned files.